# Form Validation messages Vs Language in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

After reading the docs, I've understood the strucutre in `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` to add custom error messages.

```
'custom' => [
    'name' => [
        'required' => 'Please fill the name of the company'
    ]
],
```

My problem here is that after setting this up, I won't be able to use a field called `name` to another resource, for instance a `Please fill out your name` message. When overriding the method `messages()` inside the FormRequest, I'm able to be more specific in these messages, but then I lose the `Language` customization.

My question is: How can I go about setting up custom messages for different Form Requests and still keep the language system working in my favor?

### Edit

To better explain what I want, here is a little bit of code.

```
class CompanyRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:20'
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        // Here I have specific message for Company name field, but I'm
        // stuck with one single language.
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Can you please fill the company name.',
            'name.max' => 'The name of the company cannot be bigger than 20 characters'
        ];
    }
}
```

Now the UserRequest

```
class UserRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:40',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        // Here I have specific message for User name field, but I'm stuck
        // with one single language.
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Please provide your full name',
            'name.max' => 'If your name is bigger than 40 characters, consider using only first and last name.'
        ];
    }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly, but I'm stuck with English. I can solve that with the `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file. Now, I'll erase the `messages` method and use the validation file instead.

```
'custom' => [
    // Here I can have multiple validation files for different languages,
    // but how would I go about to define the field name for other entities 
    // (such as the user message).
    'name' => [
        'required' => 'Please fill the name of the company',
        'max' => 'The field cannot have more than 20 characters',
    ]
]
```

Now, how can I differ the messages for the field `name` for **Company entity** and the field `name` for **User entity**?

To wrap it up:

- The **Form Request** provides me a way of overriding a **messages()** method that allow me to use the term `name` for multiple forms.
- The Validation file provides me a way of using multiple languages (I can create a `resources/lang/fr/validation.php`, but I can only define the field "name" once. I cannot have different messages for a field name.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean your resources/land/xx. folder should contain the translation for your validation messages. Can you be a bit more specific or provide an example of say an english and spanish scenario

Comment: @futureweb I updated my question to try and clarify more my problem.

Comment: I think this might help you http://laravel.io/forum/06-12-2014-custom-field-name-via-langget-localisation-validation

Comment: @futureweb My intent isn't to define different field names for each language, but to define different message validation for the same field name.

Comment: then what you are doing is correct? `resources/lang/en/validation.php`  would contain your english messages and `resources/lang/es/validation.php` would hold your spanish for the same form if your issue is to define lang on a different form which contains the same fieldname as anothe form your need to look at this repo: https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang